# Firebase does not report all crashes in iOS that I can see in app analytics > crashes

Tags: ios, crashlytics

At the last 30 days app store connect reports about 14 crashes but firebase crashlytics reports only about 1 crash. I suppose that crash reporting is properly set up in my app, because it sends some crashes to Firebase. Do you know why this happens and how to fix the issue?

[app store connect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCfmm.png)

[firebase crashlytics screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4c3Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to google support and the reason was missing dSYM files. I uploaded it and after several days crash count from google crashlytics even became bigger, because as app store writes "We only show Crashes from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers."